# Does `lo` have no MAC address?

Tags: network-interface, ifconfig, mac-address, loopback

From https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57935/is-a-network-interface-supposed-to-have-no-more-than-one-mac-address/57937?noredirect=1#comment100988_57937

> A network interface in a MAC-based network always requires a MAC address, **virtual** or physical.  However, there are networks that are not MAC-based.

Does`ifconfig` show `lo` as a virtual network interface? `ifconfig` doesn't show its MAC address, does it mean `lo` has no MAC address, and the network of loopback IP addresses is not MAC-based?

Thanks.

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2403613  bytes 138542051 (138.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2403613  bytes 138542051 (138.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `lo` interface is not associated with a hardware network interface (it's a virtual loopback interface), it does not have an Ethernet hardware address (MAC address).

Communication though the loopback interface is not MAC-based. No routing needs to take place to send packets between NICs.

Comment: "No routing needs to take place to send packets between NICs." Does MAC need routing? Isn't routing a concept in layer 3, while MAC is in layer 2?